# How to minimize app and keep showing the video

Tags: android

I'm working on an app with a video call, I want to know how I can continue to show the video at the bottom of the screen after minimizing the app, such as skype, allowing the user to enter other app with the video call window visible.

I have researched the draggablepanel library, however, it performs the function only with one view, I want it to be by minimizing the entire app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is called PIP, or picture in picture

Comment: I've read about pip, but it's not just for android 8 ?. I need this to work from android 5.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Android 8.0 and up, you can use the new PIP API:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

However, if you want to support older Android versions, you will need to create what is know as "Floating widget" and manage it yourself every step of the way.

Here is an example tutorial on how to do it:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-floating-widget-tutorial

Note, that with this method, Android may disable some options in some apps if your widget is displayed over them.
For example, if a user gets an app installation dialog, the "install" button will be disabled while a "system alert" window (your floating widget) is visible.
This is a security measure designed to stop certain types of malware.